# Different ways of creating Objects in Python?

Tags: python

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
```

I don't understand why they haven't used () while calling class name  SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.

Comment: Because they didn't call `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, everything is an object (meaning it can be assigned to a variable and, in many cases, manipulated by Python code) so this snippet is just assigning the value `SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` -- a class, as you recognized -- to the variable named `handler`. If you were to call `handler()`, you would get back an instance equivalent to if you had called `SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler()`